# How to set a default page for website when the server is down?

Tags: azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine

I have a website hosted on IIS installed on a Azure virtual machine.

I schedule the virtual machine to be on and allocated only during office time.

I wonder if there is any way to set a default page for when the virtual machine is off?

I use winhost as DNS.

Comment: What do you mean, "*At the moment azure handles the web request by returning a white page.*" ? Azure doesn't have default-page handling; it doesn't even know what you're using your VM for.

Comment: Thank you David, I removed that point.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, A server is down means that the server will not give out any response.
If a server can still return a write page to you, it means the server is not down.